# Add logging middle to grpc

Tags: go, grpc

I am attempting to add some logging middleware to a grpc server, I am following the simple example on their github here.

https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/master/logging/logrus/examples_test.go

I set up my server options as so:

```
var (
  logrusLogger *logrus.Logger
  customFunc   grpc_logrus.CodeToLevel
)

func main() {

    logrusEntry := logrus.NewEntry(logrusLogger)

    lorgusOpts := []grpc_logrus.Option{
        grpc_logrus.WithLevels(customFunc),
    }

    grpc_logrus.ReplaceGrpcLogger(logrusEntry)

    opt := []grpc.ServerOption{
        grpc.Creds(credentials.NewTLS(tlsConfig)),
        grpc_middleware.WithUnaryServerChain(
            grpc_auth.UnaryServerInterceptor(auther.Auth),
            grpc_logrus.UnaryServerInterceptor(logrusEntry, lorgusOpts...),
        ),
    }

    s := grpc.NewServer(opt...)
    if err := s.Serve(lis); err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("err %+v", err)
    }
}
```

However, whenever I look at the logs I am getting a nil pointer.

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
[signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x89edde]

goroutine 23 [running]:
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/logging/logrus.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1(0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0x9df7a0, 0xc0000adfc0, 0xc00018caa0, 0xc00018cac0, 0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.0/logging/logrus/server_interceptors.go:37 +0x1be
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1(0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0x9df7a0, 0xc0000adfc0, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0, 0xc0000adfc0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.0/chain.go:25 +0x63
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/auth.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1(0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0x9df7a0, 0xc0000adfc0, 0xc00018caa0, 0xc00018cae0, 0x89ceda, 0x9f24e0, 0xc00018cb00, 0xc00018caa0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.0/auth/auth.go:47 +0x108
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1(0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0x9df7a0, 0xc0000adfc0, 0xc0001a8100, 0x0, 0xc0001c5ac0, 0x40c5b8)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.0/chain.go:25 +0x63
github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1(0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0x9df7a0, 0xc0000adfc0, 0xc00018caa0, 0xc00018cac0, 0xc00008eb30, 0x56cd28, 0xa04380, 0xc00026c390)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.0/chain.go:34 +0xd5
qcap/proto/company._CompanyService_SelectCompany_Handler(0x9c43e0, 0xc00000e068, 0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0xc0000ab140, 0xc000228120, 0xb2e640, 0xc00026c390, 0xc0000a20f0, 0x26)
    /go/src/qcap/proto/company/service.pb.go:975 +0x14b
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).processUnaryRPC(0xc000001500, 0xb35300, 0xc0001da480, 0xc0001a8100, 0xc000228570, 0xf082f8, 0x0, 0x0, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.27.1/server.go:1024 +0x4f4
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc000001500, 0xb35300, 0xc0001da480, 0xc0001a8100, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.27.1/server.go:1313 +0xd97
google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1(0xc0001dce50, 0xc000001500, 0xb35300, 0xc0001da480, 0xc0001a8100)
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.27.1/server.go:722 +0xbb
created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.27.1/server.go:720 +0xa1
```

Has anyone come across this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the examples that this code is inspired from, could the problem be related to not having the "grpc_ctxtags" interceptor? See https://github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/blob/06f64829ca1f521d41cd6235a7a204a6566fb0dc/logging/logrus/examples_test.go#L31

Answer (score 3):

It is panic because of these variables are nil

```
var (
  logrusLogger *logrus.Logger
  customFunc   grpc_logrus.CodeToLevel
)
```

instead use

```
var (
  logrusLogger = logrus.New()
  customFunc   = func(code codes.Code) logrus.Level {
    if code == codes.OK {
        return logrus.InfoLevel
    }
    return logrus.ErrorLevel
  }
)
```

NOTE: `grpc_logrus.CodeToLevel` has underlying type of `func(code codes.Code) logrus.Level`

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing a similar problem:

```
panic: runtime error: invalid memory address or nil pointer dereference
 [signal SIGSEGV: segmentation violation code=0x1 addr=0x0 pc=0x8e8ffb]
 
 goroutine 38 [running]:
 github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/logging/logrus.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1(0xc98ac0, 0xc00011e9c0, 0xafa620, 0xc00011e3f0, 0xc0001164c0, 0xc000116520, 0xc98ac0, 0xc00011e9c0, 0xc000120030, 0xc00011e990)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.2/logging/logrus/server_interceptors.go:37 +0x1bb
 github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1(0xc98ac0, 0xc00011e9c0, 0xafa620, 0xc00011e3f0, 0x17, 0xafa620, 0xc00011e3f0, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.2/chain.go:25 +0x63
 github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware/tags.UnaryServerInterceptor.func1(0xc98ac0, 0xc00011e3c0, 0xafa620, 0xc00011e3f0, 0xc0001164c0, 0xc000116540, 0x8dac2a, 0xb165e0, 0xc000116560, 0xc0001164c0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.2/tags/interceptors.go:23 +0x86
 github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1.1.1(0xc98ac0, 0xc00011e3c0, 0xafa620, 0xc00011e3f0, 0xc000152100, 0x0, 0xc0001f3b30, 0x40f0a8)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.2/chain.go:25 +0x63
 github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware.ChainUnaryServer.func1(0xc98ac0, 0xc00011e3c0, 0xafa620, 0xc00011e3f0, 0xc0001164c0, 0xc0001164e0, 0xc000505ba0, 0x493578, 0xb34560, 0xc00011e3c0)
    /go/pkg/mod/github.com/grpc-ecosystem/go-grpc-middleware@v1.2.2/chain.go:34 +0xd5
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.1/server.go:1082 +0x50a
 google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).handleStream(0xc00031eea0, 0xc9ffa0, 0xc000102780, 0xc000152100, 0x0)
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.1/server.go:1405 +0xccd
 google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1.1(0xc000142020, 0xc00031eea0, 0xc9ffa0, 0xc000102780, 0xc000152100)
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.1/server.go:746 +0xa1
 created by google.golang.org/grpc.(*Server).serveStreams.func1
    /go/pkg/mod/google.golang.org/grpc@v1.29.1/server.go:744 +0xa1
```

The code causing the issue is (I imported `logrus` as `log`):

```
func InitgRPC(port int, appStruct *app.App) (*grpc.Server, net.Listener) {
    lis, err := net.Listen("tcp", fmt.Sprintf(":%s", fmt.Sprint(port)))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Failed to listen on port: %s, error: %v", fmt.Sprint(port), err)
    }

    logrusEntry := log.NewEntry(logrusLogger)

    opts := []grpc_logrus.Option{
        grpc_logrus.WithLevels(customFunc),
    }

    grpc_logrus.ReplaceGrpcLogger(logrusEntry)

    grpcServer := grpc.NewServer(
    grpc_middleware.WithUnaryServerChain(
        grpc_ctxtags.UnaryServerInterceptor(grpc_ctxtags.WithFieldExtractor(grpc_ctxtags.CodeGenRequestFieldExtractor)),
        grpc_logrus.UnaryServerInterceptor(logrusEntry, opts...),
        grpc_auth.UnaryServerInterceptor(appStruct.AuthenticateUser),
        grpc_recovery.UnaryServerInterceptor()),
    grpc_middleware.WithStreamServerChain(
        grpc_ctxtags.StreamServerInterceptor(grpc_ctxtags.WithFieldExtractor(grpc_ctxtags.CodeGenRequestFieldExtractor)),
        grpc_logrus.StreamServerInterceptor(logrusEntry, opts...),
        grpc_auth.StreamServerInterceptor(appStruct.AuthenticateUser),
        grpc_recovery.StreamServerInterceptor(),
    ),
)

    app.RegisterServer(grpcServer, appStruct)

    return grpcServer, lis
}
```

So the issue isn't related to not including the `grpc_ctxtags` interceptor as stated by Nick Pocock.